# What kind of visa do I need to move to Italy with my Italian husband?

Tags: resident-permit

My husband and I are expats living in Singapore, planning on moving back to Italy. I am an American citizen and would like to know if I need a *Visto per Motivi Familiari* or tourist visa in order to apply for residency upon our return. When I apply for residency, can I apply for the *Carta di Soggiorno* directly or do I still have to obtain a *Permesso di soggiorno* first? We have been married for 10 years but have lived out of Italy the entire time. It is time to come home but I need to understand how first.

Comment: Is your husband Italian / EU citizen?

Comment: Have you asked your local Italian consulate?

Comment: @SayedA. Hello.  Yes, my husband is an Italian EU Citizen.

Comment: @phoog Hi.  I have not yet asked the Italian consulate.  I am in the early stages of researching requirements and procedures.

Comment: @SilviaAnna I do not have time to write a proper answer now, nor even to look for related questions, but I do know that Italy has a law extending the benefits of EU freedom of movement rules to family of Italian citizens.  This means that you should not need a visa to enter Italy when you arrive there with your husband to settle, and that you will receive a carta di soggiorno. I believe Italy also has a law allowing spouses of Italians to naturalize after just a few years of marriage, even when living outside Italy, so if I'm right about that you could also become Italian even before you move.

Comment: As an American citizen you can travel to Italy and to all other members of the Schengen Area for up to 90 days for tourist or business purposes without a visa. About your second question, residency permits for Italian/EU citizens's family members are called 'Carta di soggiorno' not 'Permesso di Soggiorno' and It has 5 years validity once issued and you can apply it as soon as you arrive in Italy. You'll be required to present some documentations proving you relationship status and your husband's economic situation etc.

Comment: You might still be issued a temporary Carta di soggiorno (2-3 years) in case if your annual income is lower than the minimum social security allowance (€ 5.824,91). Good luck.

Comment: @SayedA. The financial situation should only be relevant if the husband is unemployed.  As long as he is working in Italy, under EU law (and therefore under Italian law), his family can live with him in Italy.

Comment: @Phoog you're right.